# Device Doesn't Receive message from NEW Google Cloud Messaging (NEW GCM)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-intent

please help me
i've been surfing about this topic , and still stack in this new GCM

my last project using GCM Push according this link

ht**://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

but now, the last GCM (C2DM) is deprecated, so we don't use any GCMRegistrar anymore

here, take a look at this
h**p://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html
there is a statement "Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is deprecated. The C2DM service will continue to be maintained in the short term, but **C2DM will accept no new users, and it will grant no new quotas**"

i use this link for learning the concept

and for the example i use :
https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git

i think, i have followed every steps required

i have referenced my project to google play service lib

i also have changed my sender id to my google project number

i also have received RegID from GCM

but the problem is , whenever i click the send button

it never show me anything

from google documentation example, it says that it should ECHO back to my device, but it never does

i checked in documentation
the concept says that gcmbroadcastreceiver will receive any GCM Message pushed to my device ,

so i tried to log inside the "OnReceive" in that broadcaster, 
but it never show anything

i also tried to implement HTTP GCM Server using this documentation 
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

i get the response like this 
{"multicast_id":6256370624066466203,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1378114688323559%eab45603f9fd7ecd"}]}

but my log never shows anything

here is my broadcastreceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v("HAHA BANGET","masuk ke broadcastReceiver");

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

and here is my intentservice

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("7134XXXXX");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "HAHA";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.v(TAG,"MASUK INTENT NIH");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, PushBaruLagi.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru.GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru.PushBaruLagi"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

i'm using 2.2 FROYO

and i've updated my google play services to the newest one

so guys, if anyone could please help me , thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are you testing on emulator?

Comment: `super("GcmIntentService");` should have GCM Project ID

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Try this way**

UPDATE : New GCM API implementation

1) create class GcmIntentService.java

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("your project id here");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // handle message here
    }

}
```

2) create class GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

3) Mainfest.xml

pemissions for GCM

```
<permission
        android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<receiver
            android:name="your.package.name.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="your.package.name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="your.package.name.GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

----------------------OLD API------------------------------------------------

```
public GcmIntentService() {
        super("72544799xxx"); //Pass GCM project id here
    }


<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.coba.pushgcmbaru.GCMIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

**Create GCMReceiver class and replace with your GcmBroadcastReceiver**

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

/**
 * This Class Contains All Method Related To GCMReceiver.
 * 
 * @author 
 * 
 */
public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return GCMIntentService.class.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry man, i dont get it , my apps still doesn't receive gcm message

Comment: The class GCMBroadcastReceiver and it's import has been deprecated since this answer and will now longer work. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/package-summary.html

Comment: Are you sure about that @drees? "The client helper library that was offered in previous versions of GCM still works, but it has been superseded by the more efficient GoogleCloudMessaging APIs." - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: @JCSG thank you for catching that. I jumped the gun. It will still work though it is recommended that you use the new API instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
// registration

int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

    final GoogleCloudMessaging gcm =  GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    gcm.register( Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID );

                    // old style google cloud messaging register process ----------------------
                    // Intent intent = new Intent( "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" );
                    // intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(),0));
                    // intent.putExtra("sender", Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID );
                    // startService( intent );
                    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                } 
                catch ( IOException e ) {   

                }
                catch ( Exception ex) {

                }
            }
    }).start();
}
else if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {        
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_gcm_installplayservices), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.error_gcm_devicenotsupported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

// class for all responses

public class PushNotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver implements IntentClientHubInterface {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if( intent != null && "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(intent.getAction())) {

            String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

            if( error == null && context != null) {
                Utils.saveRegistrationID( context, registrationId );
            }

        }
        else if ( intent != null && "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(intent.getAction()) ) {     

            // handle notification          

        }
    }
}

// permissions

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...

    <permission android:name="YOUR.PROJECT.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="YOUR.PROJECT.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application ...

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".PushNotificationReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="YOUR.PROJECT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```