# Android NEW GCM PUSH (With Google Play Services)

Tags: android, message, google-cloud-messaging

Is there anyone succeeded to Push GCM Message [Using Google Play Services] to Your Device?

this new gcm is really annoys me , i have research it for like 10 days non stop , and there is not a single link except

https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fgcm%2Fdemo%2Fapp

that could help me with the latest gcm push.

I've surfed for every tutorial i could open , and they all keep telling about C2DM
(with GCMRegistrar)

i think this GCM Push is released in this August 2013 , that's why it would really a pain in the ass when i try to look for its tutorial

that's why , please help to answer my questions

why is my device doesn't receive any GCM Message even though i've received this

```
{"multicast_id":5297321084194982891,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1378179100955867%77ddec76f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

as response from GCM when my server send it to GCM

Comment: You might need to post some more code. Do you have all the permissions in manifest? Have you configured you Broadcast receiver correctly? Is internet working? You might need to give us more info for the client side. Your server side seems work fine.

Comment: I have the same problem , Any one solved this issue ?

Comment: @yogie Soesanto : How you solved this issue ?

Comment: @OMAK my problem is because i use Android OS 2.2 , my code works really fine when i switch to Android OS >= 3.0

Comment: @YogieSoesanto Thanks. I have solved the problem its due wrong package name in broadcast receiver registration

Answer (score 1):

closed , i've found the problem

the problem was never in the code, it was in the OS

try to use OS 3.0 or higher , it should work well

learn more here :

[Device Doesn't Receive message from NEW Google Cloud Messaging (NEW GCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570425/device-doesnt-receive-message-from-new-google-cloud-messaging-new-gcm)

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation includes a tutorial for [Implementing the GCM Client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) using the new `GoogleCloundMessaging` API.